# Dynamically add *ngIf in a directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

how can I dynamically add an *ngIf to an element that's decorated with an attribute directive?

For a simple experiment, I tried this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[lhUserHasRights]'
})
export class UserHasRightsDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("*ngIf", "false");
    }

    ...
```

, but it didn't work. The browser showed me an error "*ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element'*: '*ngIf' is not a valid attribute name.*"

Comment: Instead of adding *ngIf, how about changing css display or visibilty attribute via the directive?

Comment: agree with vega it is not possible to add structural directives dynamically to the Dom . it has to be added driectly. make use of `[hidden]`

Comment: @RahulSingh Since the question explicitly states trying to as `*ngIf` I am not sure using `[hidden]` is the correct way to go. Hiding the element would only remove it from the rendered page but not the DOM which would allow it to be seen in the View Page Source tool in the browser. This would not be appropriate if the element contained sensitive information.

Comment: hiding it via css is absolutely a different thing. for example if you want to reset a component instance and have `ngOnInit` retriggered and of course it doesn't stop its logic like listening to events, change detection etc. just because its hidden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following suggestion is based on the [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) example from the Angular documentation.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[lhUserHasRights]'
})
export class UserHasRightsDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private hasRights = false;
    private hasView = false;

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.hasRights && !this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            this.hasView = true;
        } else if (!this.hasRights && this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
            this.hasView = false;
        }
    }

    ...
```

Now this is some other plumbing you may have to hook up depending on how you have to use your directive. For example do you want to use it like this

```
<div *lhUserHasRights>...</div>
```

or

```
<div *lhUserHasRights="condition">...</div>
```

I would suggest reading the section of the documentation in the link above.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!