# How to toggle nativeElement

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I have a custom directive in an Angular app (version 7.0.1) that deals with user permissions, removing stuff that they can't see.

The problem is that the user can be changed at any moment, so I would need to constantly toggle nativeElement. I found a way to do it, but only its visibility, which is not a secure way to do it at all.

```
  if (!this.CheckPermissionService.canPerform(this.url, roles, this.action)) {
    this.el.nativeElement.hidden = true;
  } else {
    this.el.nativeElement.hidden = false;
  }
```

There is a way to toggle nativeElement as a whole? Like, removing it and recreating it inside a directive?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403572/9386929

Comment: Are you looking some like https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1 ?

Comment: This was really what i was looking for. Thanks, Eliseo and nircraft. Could you please answer the question so I can approve it?